# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.2; I was using a previous version before I started getting this error.

Basically, I set my models with "string" properties and execute a query or stored procedure and dump the results out as strings, this has always worked.

Any ideas how to fix? Perhaps a "Convention" I could use for the conversion?

Ex:

```
SQL:
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS Id, '0', 'Test0', 'some kind of data', 'Test1', 'possibly a datetime type', 'Test2'

C#:
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Test0 { get; set; }
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}

Invalid Operation Exception:
var records = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>("select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS Id, '0', 'Test0', 'some kind of data', 'Test1', 'possibly a datetime type', 'Test2'").ToList();
```

.

Comment: I can't help but ask why you have your models with string only properties to begin with???

Comment: The data is only for display purposes only. I'm just trying to dump it out.

Comment: This is why formatting exists. :)

Comment: Please explain since I'm new to this issue. Maybe even an example.

Comment: If you want to display values, use formatting at the UI level. Don't make your model fit your displaying requirements, that's just wrong IMHO.

Comment: I'm not asking for proper design. I looking to get a job done!

Comment: I suppose you could make views and cast field values in it as varchars, and then make your model point to these views.

Comment: are you passing a string to `int Id`?

Comment: I don't believe ROW_NUMBER() returns a string.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this is a year old with no answer. I have my own answer to provide based on a comment @Crono said above.

Basically, The issue was datatypes. In order to bind SQL result set to a model Entity Framework has to translate the datatypes from SQL to .NET.

Well, in .NET I wanted everything back as a string, because the propose of the data being retrieved is not to manipulate it at all but display it out to a webpage or to a file.

The query needed to be updated to cast all result columns to a varchar. Which @Crono had kindly explained in is comment above. A view wouldn't work for me because the data/results are unknown.

**EDIT** 7/2/2016

Cast your values!

```
select Cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS Id as int), Cast('0' as varchar(255)), Cast('Test0' as varchar(255)), Cast('some kind of data' as varchar(255)), Cast('Test1' as varchar(255)), Cast('possibly a datetime type' as varchar(255)), Cast('Test2' as varchar(255))
```